# Is it possible to extend the 14-day visa-free entry in Vietnam?

Tags: visas, vietnam, swedish-citizens

Is it possible to extend the 14-day visa-free entry in Vietnam?

I have a Swedish passport, so I can enter Vietnam for 14 days without a visa.

Is it possible to extend that for another 14 days or less somewhere near Saigon? Or at all?

Answer (score 1):

Disregard the two spam answers. I firmly believe a word of caution is needed here: keep in mind that generally where visas are concerned, the only legit source is the government (and yes I know there are sometimes travel agencies that can help, but in general stick to the government's website), AND ESPECIALLY in the case of Vietnam, if the domain name doesn't end in `.gov.vn`, it is not the official website, and you should avoid these like the plague.

First, Sweden citizens get [45 days on entry](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=se&destination=vn). So that's more than what you need. Second, I read somewhere, but can't find it again, that visa exemptions can normally not be extended, but I know a couple of people who stay in Vietnam months on end with visa-free entry and extensions... I suspect some bribing is involved.

Comment: Can you please edit out the bit about spam answers, best to flag and ignore those.